# Disabled textbox value is getting lost on click of a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the following dropdown  & mapping its value into a textbox.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCntry" runat="server" Height="24px" Width="160px" 
         OnChange="Country();">
        <asp:ListItem>Select Country</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>India</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>USA</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>UK</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>


<asp:TextBox ID="TxtCntryRisk" runat="server" 
        ontextchanged="TxtCntryRisk_TextChanged" Width="153px" 
        EnableTheming="True" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
```

I have a calculation button, when I click on the button my mapped textbox value gets lost.
I want my textbox to be disabled so that its value cannot be changed.
I tried using `Readonly=true` property also but in vain. Session, viewstate also not working.

but when I enable the textbox, it's working fine, no loss of value.
any help??
thanx in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ReadOnly` attribute server side:

```
TxtCntryRisk.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");
```

Comment: again got stuck.
the above code is working but after the click of button.
before that, i m able to change the value of the textboxes.